# linux + how to monitor dropping from ifconfig or ip

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ifconfig

How to monitor RX dropped packets in Linux 7 with tcpdump ?

Or maybe any other way?

And what is RX dropped?

ifconfig results on eth1:

```
    # ifconfig -a | grep RX | grep dropped
    RX errors 0  dropped 123136  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 140938047  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0

    # ifconfig -a | grep RX | grep dropped
    RX errors 0  dropped 123136  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 140938083  overruns 0  frame 0  <--------------  after second
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch it in real time, you can use:

```
watch -tn 1  "ifconfig -a | grep -A 5 eth1 | grep 'RX packets' | sed 's/^.* dropped:\\([0-9]\\{1,\\}\\) .*\$/\1/g'"
```

Here is correct [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205141/what-exactly-is-an-ifconfig-dropped-rx-packet) why that happens.