# Does writing tcpdump output to a file on ramdisk have effect on the number of packets dropped?

Tags: kernel, tcpdump

When running `tcpdump`, I see that sometimes number of packets dropped by kernel is greater than zero (0). I was told to write to a file on ramdisk instead of a file on harddisk. I am not expert on Linux kernel or network stack, and I could not get any decent explanation about *why*.

Based on the man page of tcpdump, it seems like it happens due to a lack of buffer space, which means I need to change `-B`, not the path of output file, isn't that correct? Let's say I created a ramdisk;

```bsh
# SIZE is big enough to capture all output
> mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /var/myramdisk -o <SIZE>
```

and ran `tcpdump` with two different paths;

```bsh
# Option I
> tcpdump -U -C <FILE_SIZE> -w /var/myramdisk/option_one.pcap host 1.2.3.4 and port X

# Option II
> tcpdump -U -C <FILE_SIZE> -w /home/myhome/option_two.pcap host 1.2.3.4 and port X
```

Is there really any difference between those two commands?

Comment: I'd say no. After the `tcpdump` generates a line of output, it's buffered in local RAM, then in disk buffers (system RAM), then probably in the blocks-to-clusters on its way out to the disk or ramdisk.Network packet dropping happens on the interrupt and system level. There's no interference between them. Dropped packets are recieved packets that will be retransmitted. See `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205141/what-exactly-is-an-ifconfig-dropped-rx-packet`.